# Zip File Download in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to download a Zip file when I am getting `@uFÑÉ:Â¤µÞ(­ïÀ©zTB$ðÛYæÛLQ5ôUJñP¾C.$Ì^ÖÔ#2A,é)ÂÊâð¼mÛ¡Æ­'Þ±XRÀ¾Q¶/éhOêOþyås` this kind of data from my api end-point.
here is my code to download that zip file where I store data which I get from api end-point into generateFile:

```html
{
 this.state.generateFile ?
   <Button onClick={() => {
     const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([this.state.generateFile], { type: "application/zip" })
     );
     const link = document.createElement("a");
     link.href = url;
     link.setAttribute("saveas", "generate.zip");
     document.body.appendChild(link);
     link.click();
     this.setState({ generateFile: null });
   }} >Download</Button>
 : null
}
```

Comment: Where you fetch data and fill generateFile  ? need fetching code for more help

Comment: FYI, mixing react and direct DOM manipulation is an anti-pattern, offered only as an escape hatch if no other (react) way of doing it.

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi

this is the data fetching code :
 
  `Axios.post('https://...',
      {
        "generation_date": this.state.generateDate,
        "merchandiser": true,
        "superviser": true
      },
      {
        headers: { Authorization: "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("token") }
      }).then(
        res => this.setState({
          generateFile: res.data
        })
      )`

Comment: @DrewReese , Yeah I know it is an anti-pattern but it should not be a problem here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

call your axios with `responseType: 'arraybuffer'`

```
    Axios.post('https://...',
        {
            "generation_date": this.state.generateDate,
            "merchandiser": true, "superviser": true
        },
        {
            responseType: 'arraybuffer', // add this line 
            headers: {
                Authorization: "JWT " + localStorage.getItem("token")
            }
        }).then(res =>
            this.setState({ generateFile: res.data }
            ))
```